# @Value for custom values is not showing up

Tags: spring, spring-boot, variables, command-line

I have a project in Spring Boot (1.5.9).  I have properties in an application.properties in src/main/resources and in an external application.properties.  I also can provide values through the command line.

My main class looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableEncryptableProperties
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application {
    public Application() { super(); }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

I have a different class that looks something like this:

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationProvider extends AuthenticationProviderInterface {
    @Value("${myproject.authentication.url:https://blah:8443}")
    private String authenticationURL = "https://test.blah:8443";

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        System.err.println(authenticationURL);
    }

    ..... other stuff.....
}
```

From the System.err, I get https://test.blah:8443.

Now, I can get all of my major variables: spring.main.banner-mode, spring.datasource.name, etc.  I just do not seem to be able to get my custom variables--myproject.authentication.url or myproject.authentication.accessstring.

The spring variables are behaving as expected--I can follow precedence from the properties files to the command line.  It's only the custom variables that are giving me fits.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I'm trying to give good information, but I am typing between two unconnected computers and I will occasionally have a typo.

Thank you.

Comment: You try spelling `@Component` correctly?

Comment: I'm guessing that's just a typo for this post. Implementing `afterPropertiesSet()` implies that this is probably an `InitializingBean`, in which case Spring would be invoking that method and that it's been picked up already.

Comment: where is `@PropertySource` annotation to set the path of your properties file in which those values are set

Comment: @NullPointerException - So, as I answered below, Eclipse was "helping" me and had added in a final I wasn't expecting.  So that was the problem.  When I took out the "final" and got Eclipse to stop "helping", then this worked without @ PropertySource annotation.  All of my variables are in the standard .properties files or the command line and seem to propagate just fine, according to the precedence set up by Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Change `@Comopnent` to `@Component`.

Comment: Thank you.  I have to type between the two systems, and I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  This was blatant stupidity and Eclipse "helping" me again.  The Save actions added a "final" and (unsurprisingly) the values were not being updated.  Sorry for wasting people's time.